# How compile only c with cmake?

Tags: c, cmake

I have a c code that I insist on compile it with gcc not any c++ compiler!
I want a CMakeLists.txt for it!
Could you help me?
Here is my simple project:

```
main.c
```

Answer (score 45):

That's the basics of cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.0)
    
# here we specify that the project is C language only, so the default
# C compiler on the system will be used
project(myprogram C)

add_executable(myprogram main.c)
```

That's really all you need for compiling a C file into an executable.

Specifying your project as a `C` language project should be enough for your needs.

If that isn't enough, you can force the compiler on the command line while invoking cmake.

```
mkdir build && cd build
export CC=gcc    
cmake ..
make
```

or

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc
make
```

Please also note that, as mentioned in the comments, even when mixing languages in a project, CMake is smart enough to properly call the C compiler when encountering a file with the .c extension.

See the [documentation for the `project` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html). The syntax is slightly different when specifying additional parameters such as a version or description.

Comment: where you spesify to use c compiler in this cmake?

Comment: the `project` directive

Comment: I thought CMake automatically considered *.c files as C. No magic needed.

Comment: @rubenvb that's correct, however since one is required to specify a language by the way of the project directive, it still is the bare minimal CMakeLists.txt file that is needed.

Comment: You're wrong, at least for CMake 2.8.

Comment: I d rather use the CMake variable `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` using the -D option. instead of the `export` stuff

Comment: @mathk yes, works too

Comment: @rubenvb yes indeed, I've re-read the doc, by default a project without language specification is equivalent to have C and C++. So in the end it's still better to specify C only to avoid useless compiler checks.